# Claims auth + LDAP user display setting in SharePoint

Tags: claims-based-auth, user-profile-service, ldap

I have a claims auth site setup right now with both Windows & Forms. Providers are configured for LDAP auth. This works without an issue. I want users to be able to sign in to SharePoint using their username, aka, sAMAccountName. This also works, but I want to see the users display name in the upper corner of SharePoint while they are signed in. Here's my provider:

```
<add name="ldapMembership"
      type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
      server="cncydev.cncy.com"
      port="389"
      useSSL="false"
      userDNAttribute="distinguishedName"
      userNameAttribute="sAMAccountName"
      userContainer="CN=Users,DC=cncy,DC=com"
      userObjectClass="person"
      userFilter="(ObjectClass=person)"
      scope="Subtree"
      otherRequiredUserAttributes="sn,givenname,cn,mail,distinguishedName" />
```

My impression is that the `userDNAttribute` controls the display name of what shows in SharePoint, but this property never seems to make a difference. I've also seen `useDNAttribute="true"`, but that doesn't get respected either. For the property I want to display, does it need to be mapped to a SharePoint user profile property?

Comment: Is this Active Directory you're authenticating against, or another Directory Service?

Comment: Yes, Active Directory

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up the UPA to sync to AD, as you're aware.  On that Sync connection, you need to map the SPS-ClaimID to sAMAccountName.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit further? I'm able to authenticate against the sAMAccountName. How does mapping that to the SPS-ClaimID fix my user name issue?

Comment: It tells the UPA that the sAMAccountName (or whatever attrib your users might use as a login attribute) maps to the ClaimID.  This is how you "tell" the UPA to match user logins with UPA profiles.

Comment: Do you have any references? I have the property mapped but I feel as if there are some steps missing on my end.

Comment: I've created my AD Sync Connection to use my Ldap Membership provider, I've synced profiles over, mapped the SPS-ClaimID to the sAMAccountName and that all works fine. So what am I missing to get 'Timothy Gabrhel' to show up in SharePoint rather than 'tgabrhel'? I sign in with tgabrhel and that's all that shows. I do not want to have to update the DisplayName.

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking at the following - though they are implementing FBA which I am not sure you are.  Here is the resource: [link (msdn forums)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/af566fe9-8c93-4e40-90f6-72c24403afe2).