# SharePoint 2013 FBA LDAP Display Name - User Profile Sync

Tags: forms-authentication, ldap, user-profile-service-app

I implemented LDAP FBA on one of my sites based on this lab:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34684

It works great.
I wanted users to login using their email address, changed the userNameAttribute to mail and now users can login with their email address as it shows on the AD.

The problem is that the email address is also set as the display name.
After researching I realized this is because how their User Profile is being created so I need to setup User Profile Sync, which I did
BUT, the user profiles were created with the samAccountName as the user name so when users login with their email address, it doesn't pickup the profile and still creates a new profile based on the email...

The Profile Sync is configured for the FBA provider and all the users are being synced correctly. I used the following post to try and solve this:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2013/05/23/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-sync-for-claims-users.aspx

[Claims auth + LDAP user display setting in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37003/claims-auth-ldap-user-display-setting-in-sharepoint)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!